# Terraform: Iterating and skipping over specific index values

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to update my existing `azurerm_subnet` terraform code
by which was consumed by many others. So we really not like to break any existing `tfvars`

With the depreciated field of `network_security_group_id` from `azurerm_subnet`to a new resource called `azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association` starting with the version [2.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/2.0-upgrade-guide).

**Existing Code**

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "generic_subnet" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_names)}"

  name = "${element("${var.subnet_names}", count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.generic_vnet.name}"
  address_prefix = "${element("${var.subnet_address_ranges}", count.index)}"
  service_endpoints = "${var.service_endpoints[count.index]}"


  network_security_group_id = "${element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${element(var.subnet_route_tables, count.index)}"
}
```

**tfvars:**

```
subnet_address_ranges = [
 "10.102.40.0/22",
 "10.102.44.0/24", 
 "10.102.45.0/25"
]
subnet_names = [
 "private-subnet-01",
 "public-subnet-01", 
 "protected-subnet-01"
 ]
service_endpoints = [    
    ["Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB","Microsoft.KeyVault", "Microsoft.Storage","Microsoft.Sql","Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory","Microsoft.ContainerRegistry","Microsoft.EventHub","Microsoft.ServiceBus","Microsoft.Web"],
    [],
    ["Microsoft.KeyVault", "Microsoft.Storage"]
]
subnet_nsg_ids = [
    "/subscriptions/yyyy/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-01",
    "",
"/subscriptions/yyyy/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsg-02" 
]
```

**Updated Code** (by introducing the `azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association` resource)

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "generic_subnet" {
  count = "${length(var.subnet_names)}"

  name = "${element("${var.subnet_names}", count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.generic_vnet.name}"
  address_prefix = "${element("${var.subnet_address_ranges}", count.index)}"
  service_endpoints = "${var.service_endpoints[count.index]}"


  network_security_group_id = "${element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${element(var.subnet_route_tables, count.index)}"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "generic_nsg_association" {
  count= "${length(var.subnet_nsg_ids)}" 
  subnet_id = "${element(azurerm_subnet.generic_subnet.*.id, count.index)}"
  network_security_group_id = "${element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index)}"
}
```

Obviously my new resource will break all the tfvars by throwing the error like

> Error: Can not parse "network_security_group_id" as a resource id:
> Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "": empty url
>
> on ../../../main.tf line 41, in resource
> "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association"
> "generic_nsg_association":   41:   network_security_group_id =
> "${element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index)}"

The reason is we need to give `network_security_group_id` param. However all my existing tfvars have a structure support `subnet_nsg_ids` list with a empty string.

So my question is Is there a way to loop through only a specific Index in the list for my `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` resource. e.g, loop through only [0] and [2] but skip [1] (*because [1] is an empty string*)

Its not like I need to use `count` only. I'm happy to use `for_each` as well if this kind of skipping is possible.

Comment: But what to do with `subnet_names`? You have three of them. What happens with `public-subnet-01`?

Comment: `public-subnet-01` doesn't associated with any nsg rule at the time of running this for the first time. We will create the nsg in a separate tf files and provide the id here later for the association with the subnet.

Comment: I talk with my team and they proposed me to rewrite a new module and separate it out the `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` for better handling. Because this makes the more complex to handling future breaking releases from terraform. Anyway thanks for your answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your issue, but if you want to skip your `network_security_group_id` when there is an empty string, you can do that using:

```
network_security_group_id = element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index) != "" ? element(var.subnet_nsg_ids, count.index) : null
```

And if you want to filter out items with empty strings you can do:

```
for_each = [for idx, val in var.subnet_names): val if var.subnet_nsg_ids[idx] != ""]
```